# Trouble Connecting My Store To React-Router-Redux, but ONLY in Production

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

I looked over the other threads, but it seems to me like I'm doing everything   properly as best as I can tell. This only happens to me when I package and run my app. In development, this runs fine. I can't find the code that is making that difference though. Lots of code below.

Am I making a mistake in my implementation of React-Redux-Router? If so, I'm blind to it. Thanks for any help!

```
Uncaught Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(e)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(e)".
```

**Index.js**

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import storage from 'electron-json-storage';
import { Router, hashHistory } from 'react-router';
import { syncHistoryWithStore } from 'react-router-redux';
import axios from 'axios';
import configureStore from './store/configureStore';
import routes from './routes';

let myState;
let createStore;
let history;

function createProvider() {
    render(
      <Provider store={createStore}>
        <Router history={history} routes={routes} />
      </Provider>,
      document.getElementById('root')
    );
}


function createStoreFunction() {
    createStore = configureStore(myState);
    history = syncHistoryWithStore(hashHistory, createStore);
}


createStoreFunction();
createProvider();
```

**Routes.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';
import myMain from './containers/myMain';

export default (
  <Route path="/" component={myMain}>
    <IndexRoute component={myMain} />
  </Route>
);
```

**myMain.js**

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Header from '../components/Header';
import MainSection from '../components/MainSection';
import * as NoteActions from '../actions/notes_actions';
import style from './App.css';

@connect(
  state => ({
    notes: state.notes,
    activeNote: state.activeNote
  }),
  dispatch => ({
    actions: bindActionCreators(NoteActions, dispatch)
  })
)

export default class myMain extends Component {

  static propTypes = {
    notes: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    activeNote: PropTypes.object,
    actions: PropTypes.object.isRequired
  };

  render() {
    const { notes, activeNote, actions } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className={style.normal}>
        <MainSection actions={actions} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Webpack.config.production.js**

```
import webpack from 'webpack';
import ExtractTextPlugin from 'extract-text-webpack-plugin';
import merge from 'webpack-merge';
import baseConfig from './webpack.config.base';

export default merge(baseConfig, {

  //devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',   //  Real production
  devtool: 'source-map',  // Faux production

  entry: './app/index',

  output: {
    publicPath: '../dist/'
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.global\.css$/,
        loaders: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader?sourceMap'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /^((?!\.global).)*\.css$/,
        loaders: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader?modules&sourceMap&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
        ]
      }

    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compressor: {
        screw_ie8: true,
        warnings: false
      }
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('style.css', { allChunks: true })
  ],

  target: 'electron-renderer'
});
enter code here
```

**Webpack.config.development.js**

```
/* eslint max-len: 0 */
import webpack from 'webpack';
import merge from 'webpack-merge';
import baseConfig from './webpack.config.base';

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

export default merge(baseConfig, {
  debug: true,

  devtool: 'source-map',
  entry: [
    `webpack-hot-middleware/client?path=http://localhost:${port}/__webpack_hmr`,
    './app/index'
  ],
  output: {
    publicPath: `http://localhost:${port}/dist/`
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.global\.css$/,
        loaders: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader?sourceMap'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /^((?!\.global).)*\.css$/,
        loaders: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader?modules&sourceMap&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
        ]
      }
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development')
    })
  ],

  target: 'electron-renderer'
});
```

**configureStore.prod.js**

```
import { applyMiddleware, createStore, compose } from 'redux';
import {responsiveStoreEnhancer} from 'redux-responsive';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { hashHistory } from 'react-router';
import { routerMiddleware, push } from 'react-router-redux';
import rootReducer from '../reducers';
import storage from '../utils/storage';

const router = routerMiddleware(hashHistory);

const enhancer = compose(
  responsiveStoreEnhancer,
  applyMiddleware(thunk, router),
  storage(),
  window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension({ }) : nope => nope
);

export default function configureStore(initialState) {
  const store = enhancer(createStore)(rootReducer, initialState);

  if (window.devToolsExtension) {
    window.devToolsExtension.updateStore(store);
  }

  return store;
}
```

**configureStore.dev.js**

```
import { applyMiddleware, createStore, compose } from 'redux';
import {responsiveStoreEnhancer} from 'redux-responsive';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { hashHistory } from 'react-router';
import { routerMiddleware, push } from 'react-router-redux';
import rootReducer from '../reducers';
import storage from '../utils/storage';
import * as noteActions from '../actions/notes_actions';

import createLogger from 'redux-logger';

const actionCreators = {
  ...noteActions,
  push,
};

const logger = createLogger({
  level: 'info',
  collapsed: true,
});

const router = routerMiddleware(hashHistory);

const enhancer = compose(
  responsiveStoreEnhancer,
  applyMiddleware(thunk, router, logger),
  storage(),
  window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension({ actionCreators }) : nope => nope
);

export default function configureStore(initialState) {
  const store = enhancer(createStore)(rootReducer, initialState);


  if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept('../reducers', () => {
      const nextRootReducer = require('../reducers');
      store.replaceReducer(nextRootReducer);
    });
  }
  return store;
}
```

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html tabindex="-1">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <div id="root"></div>
    <script>
      {
        const script = document.createElement('script');
        const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
        script.src = (process.env.HOT) ? `http://localhost:${port}/dist/bundle.js` : '../dist/bundle.js';
        document.write(script.outerHTML);
      }
    </script>
    <script>
      if (!process.env.HOT) {
        const link = document.createElement('link');
        link.rel = 'stylesheet';
        link.href = '../dist/style.css';
        document.write(link.outerHTML);
      }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Load the code in the browser and try to find what the resulting code for index.js looks like. If it is too uglyfied, use Chrome's pretty formatter https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/pretty-print?hl=en. I think it may be reordering or changing the implementation of it in such a way that it doesn't run in the same order as you are expecting

Comment: Thanks for your advice!

I managed to get it working, but I'm not entirely clear on how I accomplished it unfortunately.

I believe it was webpack related. In another webpack file I hadn't included here, the loader was checking for .jsx, instead of just .js.

It was using that setting for development and production, so I'm not really sure why development worked for me in the first place.